# How to make a port recalculate dependencies

Tags: freebsd, configure, bsd-ports

I am trying to install [`mail/pine-pgp-filters`](https://svnweb.freebsd.org/ports/head/mail/pine-pgp-filters/) on my FreeBSD box, but I am running into a problem. I first tried to install it without having GPG installed, and it listed `security/gpg1` as a dependency. I wanted gpg2 (`security/gpg`), and so I built and installed that. I then attempted to re-install `pine-pgp-filters`, but it still prompted me to install gpg1.

I have confirmed that it is compatible with gpg2, and this segment of [the Makefile](https://svnweb.freebsd.org/ports/head/mail/pine-pgp-filters/Makefile?view=markup) should take care of which version to use:

```makefile
# We want to be version-agnostic here, but also record the right dependency
# if the user installs the package and already has one or the other installed.
.if exists(${LOCALBASE}/bin/gpg2)
BUILD_DEPENDS=  gpg2:${PORTSDIR}/security/gnupg
RUN_DEPENDS+=   gpg2:${PORTSDIR}/security/gnupg
.else
BUILD_DEPENDS=  gpg:${PORTSDIR}/security/gnupg1
RUN_DEPENDS+=   gpg:${PORTSDIR}/security/gnupg1
.endif
```

So, my question is: how do you make a port re-consider its dependencies? And if that isn't my problem, then what is?

I am happy with solutions using ports directly, `portmaster`, `pkg`, whatever.

Comment: After installing `gpg2`, did you run `make clean` in your target port's directory? If not, it will still contain cached config output that indicates that `gpg2` isn't installed, and will thus default to the older version.

Comment: @D_Bye I tried `make clean`, `make distclean`, `make rmconfig`, everything. No luck.